# Unexpected behavior of string within Task infinite loop c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, action

There is a string value named "word" inside the Synth class that acts in weird way. It changes completely each breakpoint iteration while I'm debugging when it's supposed to just stay put until I press space. If I write "hello" I'll get "he" then "heo" then "hll". I don't get why this is happening since this variable is not accessed from anywhere else and . What's going on?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Synth synth = Synth.Instance;

        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Run(() => synth.ReadConsole(tokenSource.Token), tokenSource.Token);
        Task.WaitAll(synth.ReadConsole(tokenSource.Token));
    }
}
public sealed class Synth
{
    SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    static readonly Synth _instance = new Synth();
    public static Synth Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }

    }
    protected Synth()
    {

        text.Add("test");


    }
    public List<string> text = new List<string>();
    public async Task ReadConsole(CancellationToken token)
    {
        string word = "";
        while (true)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                Char key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                if (key == ' ')
                {
                    text.Add(word);
                    word = "";
                    synthesizer.SpeakAsync(text[text.Count - 1]);

                }
                else
                {
                    word += key.ToString();
                }
            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry I know this code would be a KISS principle's arch nemesis

Comment: If it's not supposed to change until you hit space, shouldn't your if(key == ' ') not be != ? Are your if / else the wrong way around? Right now you enter a console key, you check if its space, if its not space you append the key to the variable word.

Comment: It's bad taste but that part works as it should. It's not the issue I. referring to.

Comment: if  this is async Task, I would expect to see not only return but `await` have you used the debugger to step through the code..?

Comment: Why do you invoke `ReadConsole` *twice*?

Comment: ok I'm stupid I forgot that WaitAll actually calls the action. Thanks serpent5